# Polynomials that do not exist

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

> Prove that it is not possible to find 4 polynomials $a(x), b(x), c(x), d(x)$ with real coefficients such that $a(x)<b(x)<c(x)<d(x)$ for $0<x<1$ and $b(x)<d(x)<a(x)<c(x)$ for $-1<x<0$.

I have shown that $a[0]=b[0]=c[0]=d[0]$. Please give some hints from this.

Answer (score 1):

We may assume wlog that $a$ is the zero polynomial (namely, replace $b$ with $b-a$ etc.). Then $b,c,d$ are not the zero polynomial, but
with what you found, we have $b(0)=c(0)=d(0)=0$.
So we can write $b(x)=x^{k_b}\cdot \tilde b(x)$, $c(x)=x^{k_c}\cdot \tilde c(x)$, $d(x)=x^{k_d}\cdot \tilde d(x)$ where $\tilde b(0), \tilde c(0), \tilde d(0)$ are all non-zero and $k_b,k_c,k_d$ are positive integers.
Let $m=\min\{k_b,k_c,k_d\}$. Then
$\hat a(x):=\frac {a(x)}{x^m}=0$, $\hat b(x):=\frac {b(x)}{x^m}$, $\hat c(x):=\frac {c(x)}{x^m}$, $\hat d(x):=\frac {d(x)}{x^m}$ are polynomials with
$$\hat a(x)<\hat b(x)<\hat c(x)<\hat d(x) $$
for $0<x<1$ and (depending on parity of $m$) either
$$ \hat b(x)<\hat d(x)<\hat a(x)<\hat c(x)$$
or
$$ \hat b(x)>\hat d(x)>\hat a(x)>\hat c(x)$$
for $-1<x<0$.
In both cases, we can again show that $0=\hat a(0)=\hat b(0)=\hat c(0)=\hat d(0)$.
But $m$ equals one of $k_b,k_c,k_d$, so that the corresponding hatted polynomial is non-zero at $x=0$ -- contradiction!